# fetch variables in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django .
I am facing a small problem but unable to solve it.
In my template when I try to access any variable using {{ }} but it returns blank while displaying something as detailview.whereas it works fine in listview.

CODE:urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

                           url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
                                  queryset=Profile.objects.all().order_by("First_Name"),
                                  template_name="STUDENT_REGISTRATION.html")),
                           url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',DetailView.as_view(
                                  model=Profile,
                                  template_name="Profile.html")),
```

TEMPLATE:

```
{%extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}


<h2>Registration No. :- {{ Profile.Registration_No }} <br>
    Full Name : {{ Profile.First_Name }} {{ Profile.Last_Name }} </h2>


<div class="Profile_meta">
{{ Profile.Date_of_Birth}}
</div>

<div class="Profile_body">
{{ Profile.Permanent_Address|safe|linebreaks }}
</div>


{%endblock%}
```

Plz help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to your Profile instance as:

```
    {{ object.First_Name }} {{ object.Last_Name }}
```

By the way, take a look at PEP8, try to keep CamelCaseNames for class names and underscores_names for instances. It will make your code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks.. it works!!
and ya i'll take care of naming in future.